# SyntaxError: Illegal return statement in Angular application

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting **SyntaxError: Illegal return statement** while running beow code in last line of code(**return** statement). And after executing last line, I'm getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined** error.

```
constructor(private _http:Http);
createCategory(vm: Category): Observable<any>{  
vm.Id = 25;
var body = JSON.stringify(vm);
var headerOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });   
return this._http.post('http://localhost:55861/api/CategoryApi', body, {headers: headerOptions }).map(x => x.json());
}
```

I'm running Angular project in visual studio. The above code is for posting the data to web api POST action method. Can anyone help me out?..

Comment: Can you show the whole class? Or at least the constructor

Comment: Seems like the class doesn't know what this._http is, are you injecting it?

Comment: Yes ..I'm injecting it.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the content-type to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, my main problem solved...ie. while debugging, able to call Post action method of WebAPI(ie., compiler is going to API Post method while running, which was not going earlier).

```
var headerOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headerOptions });
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:55861/api/CategoryApi/Post', body, requestOptions).map(x => x.json());
```

But now the problem is, what should to do with below line?.. Since I changed content-type to *other than json type* and also the data from client is **null**(in POST of API) as for now. Can anyone help me out for this..Thanks in Advance..

```
body, requestOptions).map(x => x.json());
```